# Install ubuntu on mac with no OS

Tags: system-installation, mac

I have a mid-2009 MacBook Pro with no OS and I would like to install Ubuntu on.

It is stuck with a flashing question mark folder.

Is there a way I can install Ubuntu using a USB on this Mac? Note that I can't get past this question mark, I've tried most things in the support site. I cannot find a source that aims on how to install Ubuntu with this condition.

[image: error image of folder with question mark]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you boot from a pendrive? You will need to make a bootable ubuntu pendrive to install it.
Then, according to this link
[How to boot a Mac from USB media](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/usb-boot/)

You could boot from it and star you journey.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check that out!